# MVC open PDF in pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my application i have a pdf document in my solution and when user clicks a particular button the document must be opened in a popup window. I could open it in the same window by just returning the filestream object .The code i used.

```
public ActionResult ShowPdf()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/downloads/MyPdf.pdf")))
        {
            string pathSource = Server.MapPath("~/downloads/MyPdf.pdf");
            FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(pathSource, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            return new FileStreamResult(fsSource, "application/pdf");
        }
        else
        {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
    }
```

How can i load the same in a popup window

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on how you are calling this controller action from the client. For example if you have a link, you could add the `target="_blank"` attribute to this anchor. For example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Download pdf",
    "ShowPdf",
    "SomeController",
    null,
    new { target = "_blank" }
)
```

Alternatively if you are using javascript to invoke the controller action, you could use the [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open) function.